# 浮動小数点のbool判定について

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, deeplearning4j

pytorchのtorch.nn.Linearモジュールをnumpyで再現しようとしています。
結果は多少誤差がでたため、小数点を切捨ててboolの判定を出力してみました。
切り捨てた結果は同じ数字にもかかわらすFalse判定になってしまうのはなぜでしょうか？
私自身コンピュータサイエンスには詳しくないため、どなたかご教授お願いします。

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from module import Linear # 自作のモジュール
np.random.seed(42)

# 自作モジュール
x = np.random.randn(2,3,3,4)
affine = Linear(4,6)

# torch.nn.Linear
xt = torch.tensor(x).float()
linear = nn.Linear(4,6)

# nn.Linearのパラメータを自作モジュールに上書き
weight = linear.weight.detach().numpy().copy()
affine.weight = weight
bias = linear.bias.detach().numpy().copy()
affine.bias = bias

# 自作モジュールの出力
y = affine(x)
print(y[0][0][0][0]) # 一部を出力
>>> -0.4672098047691683

# nn.Linearの出力
yt = linear(xt).detach().numpy().copy()
print(yt[0][0][0][0]) # 一部を出力
>>> -0.46720976 

# boolで確認するとFalseになってしまう.....
print(np.round(y[0][0], decimals=3) == np.round(yt[0][0], decimals=3))
>>> array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

Comment: タイトルは「bool判定」よりも「同値判定」とか「等価判定」とした方が理解しやすいのでは？

Comment: 同値や等価といった概念があるのですね！勉強になりました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
xをxtに変換する際にnp.float64からtorch.float32にへ変換されていました。
そのため、出力ytをtonserからndarrayにに戻した際にnp.floa32へ変換されていました。
y(float64)とyt(float32)で同じ値にもかかわらずデータ型が一致していながいがためにFalseの判定になっていたようです。